# Sketch the region of integration of $\int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt {9-y}} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy$

Tags: integration

What would the region of integration of this look like? How would you express the same region if you were to change the order of integration? $$\int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt {9-y}} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy$$

I'm not sure if I'm visualizing it right; would it be correct if I said that because a horizontal slice at any given $y$ is $x=\sqrt {9-y}$, then $y=9-x^2$? And then I just take the appropriate section of the graph of $y=9-x^2$, which is the part that lies in the first quadrant and is bounded by $y=3$ and the $x$ and $y$ axes? Am I doing it right?

For the second part of the question, how would I express the same region if I were to change the order of integration? Would $\int_0^3 \int_0^{9-x^2}f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$ be correct, or is it off?

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: What you don...?

Comment: I know the enter thing :) Do you want me to draw the region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good to sketch first. I was wrong... See the picture below. If we integrate $f(x,y)$ at a given $y$ with respect to $x$ then the limits are $0, \sqrt{9-y}$. But then the integral with respect to $y$ has to go from $0$ to $9$:
$$\int_0^9\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{9-y}}f(x,y)\ \ dx\right)dy.$$

Then, the other way around

$$\int_0^3\left(\int_0^{9-x^2}f(x,y) \ \ dy\ \right)dx.$$

[image]

Or, if the formula
$$\int_0^3\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{9-y}}f(x,y)\ \ dx\right)dy$$is given, that is, if we have to integrate over the red region then the reverse order integral will look like

$$\int_0^\sqrt{6}\left(\int_0^3f(x,y)\ \ dy\right)dx+\int_\sqrt{6}^3\left(\int_0^{9-x^2}f(x,y)\ \ dy\ \right)dx.$$

Comment: I am done now .

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks! (By the way, now that there's a finished answer, should we should delete our comments to make things "cleaner"?)

Comment: No! Everybody has to see that we try to think -- hard :)

Comment: Crap, too late! :(

Comment: Fair enough, this way or that way  :D