# Change the order of expectation

Tags: integration, expectation

Sorry this might be a silly question, but I'm kind of confused and really want to make sure I'm correct.

Let $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ be $n$  i.i.d. random variables with the same range of $[\underline{v}, \overline{v}]$ and the same CDF $F(v_i)$. Let $G(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ be a function of the $n$ random variables.

Is it true that we can always freely change the order of the expectations?

For example, is it true that

$E_1[E_2[E_3[\dots[G(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)]\dots]]]
=E_1[E_3[E_2[\dots[G(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)]\dots]]]$
?

If not, what conditions do I need for equalities like the one above to be true?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is $E_i$ ?

Comment: E_i  is just the expectation with respect to v_i, the i_th random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are $n$ i.i.d random variables with the same range and the same CDF $F(v_i)$ and $G(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$ is some function of them, then $G(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$ is itself a random variable, and its expected value $\operatorname{E}(G(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n))$ is a scalar, not a non-constant random variable.  It has no randomness it it.  The expected value of a constant is itself, so one could say $\operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(G(v_1,\ldots,v_n)))=\operatorname{E}(G(v_1,\ldots,v_n))$.

Since they are i.i.d., one could say the expected value is
$$
\operatorname{E}(G(v_1,\ldots,v_n)) = \int\cdots\int G(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,dF(x_1)\cdots dF(x_n) = c.
$$
If one iterates the expectation one is merely integrating a constant over a space of measure $1$:
$$
\operatorname{E}(c) = \int\cdots\int c\,dF(x_1)\cdots dF(x_n) = c.
$$
(The same c.d.f. $F$ appears $n$ times here, since they are identically distributed, and $\Pr(X_1\le x_1\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n\le x_n)$ is simply the product $F(x_1)\cdots F(x_n)$ because $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are independent.)

As "zoli" has pointed out in a comment, the meaning of your subscripts in "$\operatorname{E}_i$" is unclear at best.

Comment: By E_i, I mean the expectation with respect to the i_th random variable, that is, v_i.

Comment: @larrybr : There's no such thing as "expectation with respect to" a particular random variable. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: All of these random variables must be taken to have as their domain a particular probability space $\Omega$ with a probability measure $P$.   So we have $\displaystyle\operatorname{E}(G(v_1,\ldots,v_n)) = \int_\Omega G(v_1(\omega),\dots,v_n(\omega))\, P(d\omega)$.  You're integrating over the whole space $\Omega$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

I gather this non-standard shorthand is to indicate the order of integration, thusly:

$$\mathsf E_1(\mathsf E_2(\ldots \mathsf E_n(G(V_1,V_2,\ldots, V_n)\ldots)) = \iint\cdots\int_\Omega G(v_1,v_2, \ldots, v_n)\;\mathrm d\mathsf F(v_n)\cdots\mathrm d\mathsf F(v_2)\;\mathrm d\mathsf F(v_1)$$

If that's the case, then the Fubini–Tonelli theorem states that if $G$ is a measurable function over the joint support (which *is* a measure space), and $\mathsf E(\lvert G(\bullet)\rvert)$ is finite when integrated in any order, then the order of integration of $\mathsf E(G(\bullet))$ will be irrelevant to the result.

Comment: Thanks Graham, that's actually what I thought. I post this question since I didn't take measure theory so wasn't very sure of that. So your answer is yes we can change the order?

Comment: It appears that the original poster did intend something like this, but one should explain that there's something wrong with the notation used and with the idea of "expectation with respect to" a particular random varaible, which the original poster mentions in a comment under my answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Isn't it fine to speak of an expectation w.r.t. a particular RV as in the above case, all the RVs are independent and therefore, the expectation over the joint probability decomposes into the expectation w.r.t. to the individual probability densities?

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly talking about the following integral:

$$\iint \cdots \int G(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n)\,dF_1\,dF_2\cdots dF_n.$$

"Freely changing the order of integration" is a calculus issue. Probability theory does not have specific rules in this respect.

Comment: This integral is simply $\operatorname{E}(G(v_1,\ldots,v_n))$.  The meaning of the iteration of expectation operators is another question, and it's not about the order of integration.

Comment: Sry, but what do you mean by "another question?" Could u please be more specific? Thx!

Comment: I meant the general question related to specific questions like the one asked and answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287049/sketch-the-region-of-integration-of-int-03-int-0-sqrt-9-y-fx-y-dx-d/1287083#1287083

Comment: @zoli, so we can change the order of integration here as well, like in the link you post?

Comment: Yes we can just like there.